# String processing in Process builder

Tags: process-builder

I have a custom text field on an object which contains text in the form of CSV.
I need to be able to take some action(create case) based on the prefixes of content in csv.(Eg AB1234,CD2345) then I need to check the prefix, i.e AB or CD and create a case for AB. Is there any way to do this in process builder formula criteria?

Comment: Do you just need the starting alpha characters of the entire string? Or do you need the starting alpha characters after each comma?

Comment: I need the starting alpha characters after each comma.

Comment: Yeah you need `Apex`, then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function BEGINS () in your formula.
Syntax : (BEGINS(fieldName, "Prefix"))
Example : (BEGINS(Name, "ABC"))